# What do you call the stores on the front of a building?

Tags: obscure-terms

What do you call the stores on the front of a building(department stores or apartment) (on ground floor usually) that face the roads with its own entrance?

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage. Could you demonstrate any research you have done on this? That would help with an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Though not really *obscure,* the technical terms are [storefronts](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/storefront) and [shopfronts](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/shop%20front). Usually this refers to the bottom floor (sometimes bottom few floors) of commercial real estate where the shops are leased from the main structure and have an on-street presence.

While some buildings have multiple stores, the storefronts are the ones that face outside/or main hallways *and have display windows.* Inside they are just shops, stores, bodegas, and retail space *if they don't have display windows*.

More about them [here on Wikipedia.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Storefront)

Comment: Really, Patterson? So if I have a store or shop trading in X or Y or Z it would make a significant difference to you whether that store in your view *faced outside*?

If you are really hoping to show a difference between storefronts that face outside and those which are really just shops, stores, and retail space then would you mind explaining what difference you see?

Comment: There, is that better? @RobbieGoodwin

Comment: Uh… what did you mean by that, please?

Comment: Okay, so in some highrises there are stores that don't have any windows. They simply have a door, just like any other tenant, but instead of it being Bob's apartment it might be Fred's store. No sign on the door. If the door is open, then the business is open. No storefront.

Comment: In advertising/marketing of Real Estate, and I've designed a few storefronts, the ones that have a storefront are more expensive retail spaces. There is a difference.

Comment: I also added bodega to the description for the non-street level non-shop-front style stores.

Comment: In my book the stores on the front of a building are called *stores* or *shops*, the difference being US American or British.

A *storefront* is what’s seen looking at the *store* square on: doors, windows, signage, fascia, etc.

If single storey or high-rise matters, please explain how.

I’ve never found stores without windows except underground. What has only a door, above ground, is an office; never a shop or store.

*No sign on the door* indicates at least one foot in the black market; wholly irrelevant to architecture or real estate.

Comment: And what "book" might that be? You write one? Care to answer this question and supply a reference, I'm dying to read it since I've cited my sources. Sorry this site is about *English;* if you would care to cite references about how they do things across the pond go ahead. Unfortunately you know what they say about opinions though.